# Jenkins update SVN

Tags: git, svn, jenkins

I have a repo in GIT and I would like to create a task in Jenkins that takes a project from GIT and commits it into SVN. I have problems committing into SVN. I've been looking but didn't found a solution. Also the [SVN Publisher plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SVN+Publisher) is not working. Are there any plugin or a way to commit data in SVN in Jenkins? maybe executing a script?

Comment: Well, as last resort, you can commit via command line tools. Did you reckon this idea?

Comment: What problems? What do you mean by "not working"? Please include any error messages, example configurations of what you tried, and any other relevant details.

Comment: I'm not looking for a solution with the plugin because I didn't found any, and there are a lot of topics about that. The problem is that the plugin don't log anything. They output is: Attempting to import to SVN: svn://<url>
SVN Publisher: target: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/test - Upload SVN
Finished: SUCCESS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As It was mention you can directly run command from Execute shell -> This will be executing DURING job. 
You can use Postbuild Plugin to run command AFTER job, this can be tricky but it's problematic as well.

So, you are cloning something from git repo. You have these files in workspace. Note, that Jenkins have env variables -> ${WORKSPACE}.

After cloning, just write in Execute Shell `svn add .` or `svn ci -m "Some msg"`

Jenkin's job will show every step of commiting/adding.

Answer (score 0):

In Jenkins you can run scripts in post build tasks or straight into the build execute shell command.

So can simply run a custom SVN publishing script in any of these steps.